# How can I force the svelte compiler to include a style rule?

Tags: svelte, sapper

I'm trying to pass an additional class to a component through a custom property but the compiler detects that the class is not in use and does not include it. Given this component:

```
<script>
    import {createEventDispatcher} from 'svelte';

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    export let imageUrl = null;
    export let cssClass = '';
    export let data = null;

    function handleImageClick(e){
        dispatch('press', {element:this, event: e, props: $$props });
    }
</script>
<style>
    .image-button{
        width:100px;
        height: 72px;
    }
</style>

<div class="image-button {cssClass}" on:click={handleImageClick} style="background:url({imageUrl});background-size: cover;"></div>
```

I create an instance like this and pass it my additional class through the cssClass prop:

```
<script>
   import ImageButton from './components/ImageButton.svelte';

   let imgUrl = "/images/test.png";
</script>
<style>
   .my-image-button{
      border: 1px solid white;
   }
</style>
<ImageButton imageUrl={imgUrl} cssClass="my-image-button" />
```

The ImageButton instance is created and it has the additional "my-image-button" class but the style rule I declared in .my-image-button is not included. Is there a way to force the compiler to include a style rule or another workflow to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the parent component, change `.my-image-button` to `:global(.my-image-button)`. That way, Svelte will know that it needs to preserve that selector.

If you want to ensure that the CSS only applies to elements with that class *inside* the component where the styles are declared, you can use a wrapper element:

```html
<div>
  <ImageButton .../>
</div>

<style>
  div :global(.my-image-button) {
    /* ... */
  }
</style>
```